# Can you describe the Galerkin numerical method to solve the wave equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, wave-equation, galerkin-methods

How would you describe the Galerkin method to solving the wave equation
$$u_{tt}= c^2\Delta u$$
to someone who wants to implement it immediately?

More precisely, we want to solve the Cauchy problem
$$u_{tt}= c^2\Delta u , \\  u_t(x,y,z,0)= g(x,y,z) , \\ u(x,y,z,0)= f(x,y,z)$$
where $f, g$ are given compactly supported functions.

Say in a bounded region of the space we are interested in, say a ball of radius $R$, note that the wave propagates towards the boundary of the region, the sphere, thus we can't impose the condition at the boundary.

How would you implement this method ?
I am looking for a description of the finite elements, how to decompose this region? (you can use any other shape, not necessarily a ball, take a cube for example), then describing the numerical algorithm necessary to find the values of the solution $u$ at certain element or node $(x,y,z,T)$ at time $T$

Comment: I'm not sure a layman's explanation of FEM is sufficient to implement a FEM scheme in a multidimensional domain. Maybe in a 1D domain (though in 1D we have the d'Alembert solution...)

Comment: You need to search for "Galerkin method" instead of "Galkerin"

Comment: And even Galkerin gets autocorrected to [Galerkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galerkin_method) by google. The link takes you to the references.

Comment: Thank you, the typo has been corrected

Comment: @Ian I am thinking we can fix a Cartesian regular grid $(x_i,y_j,z_k)$ in the space, which gives us volume elements that are cubes?

Comment: That already complicates matters with regards to what the basis elements have to be, compared to elements with fewer vertices. (Also, if your domain can be mapped onto a regular grid, do you really even need FEM instead of finite differences?)

Comment: Numerical methods are not easy. You will need to pick up a reputable textbook or some other source to tackle this question. A brief answer on MSE will not suffice.

Comment: @K.defaoite I am looking for a good source or text, I start to doubt if the question make sense.